# if (id==1) printf("%i", id) prints some random value

Tags: c, printf

Ok. This is got to be one of the weirdest errors I have faced. I have these 2 lines in my code

```
 int id=i*2000*512+512*row+column;
 if (id==1){printf("This is output %f %f %f %i \n",entire_red[id],entire_green[id],entire_blue[id],id);}
```

and it gives me the output

> This is the output 0.000000 0.000000
>   0.000000 109456488.

I have no clue what's happening!

Comment: What is the type of `entire_red`, `entire_green` and `entire_blue`? If they are not a floating point type, then that is your problem.

Comment: What are `entire_red`, etc.?  Are they arrays of `double`s or `float`s?

Comment: @dreamlax: The question is why `id == 1` is true when printed is shows `109456488`

Comment: @Tim Cooper: I know what the question is, but if the `entire_red` variable is not a floating point type, printf will be walking the stack incorrectly.

Comment: Still surprising that the big c compilers don't have a warning built in for that. Mistakes with printf are common, and if the first parameter is a compile time constant the compiler can infer the expected types. (This is of course only possible for a few selected function like printf and not every vararg function)

Comment: @Manish - are you familiar with using a symbolic debugger with C e.g. dbx or gdb.    Its one way you can see how individual function calls take their arguments from the stack.  [Assuming you're not on a RISC cpu! :-) ]

Comment: @Tim Did you read and/or comprehend what dreamlax wrote? The statement was correct and was in fact the (obvious) source of the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `%f` format specifier expects a `double` (`float` is implicitly converted to `double` for variadic functions). If `variable_red` et al are not `float` or `double` variables, then `printf` will be processing the arguments incorrectly, and that could explain why the `id` integer is printing incorrectly.

Try this:

```
if (id==1)
    printf("This is output %f %f %f %i\n", (double)entire_red[id],(double)entire_green[id],(double)entire_blue[id],id);
```

Alternatively, ensure you are using the correct format specifiers for the `entire_red`, `entire_green` and `entire_blue` variables.

Comment: Thanks all.I had entire_red/green/blue as int arrays and was using %f .Now i corrected that back to %i and it works fine.

Comment: I believe this is a correct possible explanation.  Take note about function prototypes in 'K & R' & passing argument types which match the function declaration.   Stack misalignment is a common side effect of this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include `stdio.h`? If you don't, the compiler might select a calling convention not compatible with `printf`, which will pick up "random" values.

Comment: Though I didn't do the -1, had if the OP didn't include `stdio.h`, compiler errors should definitely prevail upon use of `printf`.

Comment: I really don't understand the down-vote. I've spent the last 14 years of my life writing C compiler for the embedded world. If `stdio.h`isn't included, the compiler will assume it's a Kernighan&Richie function and pass parameters accordingly, typically in processor registers. As `printf` takes a variable number of parameters, it will typically expect to find it's arguments on the stack.

Comment: @Mahesh: Unlike C++, it is legal to call a function in C without declaring it, so the compiler should at most issue a warning.

Comment: You are correct. +1 from me since I didn't knew it earlier. http://ideone.com/gILoT

Answer (score -1):

The `%i` is printing wrong values because `%i` is awaiting an pointer address to an integer. 
So you have to pass `&id` instead of `id`.

I think the rest of the printf format is already described by other answers.

Comment: %i is the format for a signed integer.  I do not believe this answer is correct.